# How do I group by and order by count in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

How do translate this SQL into Ruby/Rails?

```
select tag, count(*) c from tags group by tag order by c desc;
```

I found that I can do:

```
Post.select(:user_id).group(:user_id).count
Post.count(group: :user_id)
Post.all(group: :user_id, select: "user_id, count(*) as count")
Post.find(:all, select: "user_id, count(*) as count", group: :user_id)
```

#1 returns a hash. #2, #3, and #4 gave deprecation warnings. (I'm using Post because I don't have any data for Tag yet.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 Tag.select("tag, count(*) as total_count").group("tag").reverse_order
```

For more information read : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: I had to tweak it: `Tag.select("tag, count(*) as total_count").group("tag").order("total_count").reverse_order`

Comment: `reverse_order` doesn't accept arguments. I ended with: `self.tags.select(:tag, "count(*) as count").group(:tag).order(count: :desc).map {|t| t.tag }.join(' ')`. Thanks!

Comment: That still won't work: `ERROR:  column "tags.id" must appear in the GROUP BY...` I think if you don't specify the column to order, it defaults to `id` column, which is not in the `select`.